# The argument type 'Function' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String? Function(String?)?'

Tags: flutter, function

I got this error and i don't know what is the reason to solve it.

```
class PasswordTextFormField extends StatelessWidget {

  final Function validator;
  final String name;

  PasswordTextFormField({required this.name, required this.validator});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(
      validator: validator, // here it gives the error
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
        hintText: name,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and it gives this kind of error:

> The argument type 'Function' can't be assigned to the parameter type
> 'String? Function(String?)?'.

In case you didn't get what I said:

[Screenshot](https://ibb.co/0BVdygX)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: add an anonymous function with an argument

Comment: please share your code looks like your validator function return type don't match with the expected return type of Validator

Comment: Mr.Faizan where can i get InTouch with you please?

Comment: Mr. Zabaykal how I don't get it

Answer (score 0):

since [validator](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FormField/validator.html) can be null you have to provide `?` in the callback function as

```
final Function? validator;
```

and use it as

```
 validator: validator!,
```

Similarly the function which you are passing should also be nullable

```
String? validateMyInput(){
  // your code
}
```

Comment: Mr Ashutosh.

it gaves the same error, i don't get it what do you mean by passing should be nullable?

Answer (score 0):

The validator expects a function which has a nullable string argument and nullable string return type. Something like:

```
String? validatingFunction(String? text) {
}
```

Since you are not properly declaring your validator variable, you are getting this error. To fix this, change your variable declaration to:

```
final FormFieldValidator<String?> validator;
```

Read about [validator](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FormField/validator.html) and [FormFieldValidator](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FormFieldValidator.html).

Answer (score 0):

this is because TextInputField require a function which expects a string value as a argument and return either null or a string. but you are trying to give it any function which does not match the type it requires.
change your code as follows

`````
  final String? Function(String value) validator;
  final String name;

  PasswordTextFormField({required this.name, required this.validator});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(
      validator: validator, // here it gives the error
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
        hintText: name,
      ),
    );
  }
} ````
`````